# Galois Group of a Extension

Tags: galois-theory

Let be the extension of fields $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ with $\alpha=\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}$. If I haven't miscalculated, the degree of the extension is 8 and the statement of my problem says that the extension is galois and to calculate its elements. However I only find 4 $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{2})$ which are $\sigma_1$=Identity, $\sigma_2$ is determined by $\sigma_2$($\alpha$)=$\alpha$,
$\sigma_2$($\sqrt{2}$)=$-\sqrt{2}$,
$\sigma_3$ is determined by
$\sigma_3$($\alpha$) =-$\alpha$,
$\sigma_3$($\sqrt{2}$)=$\sqrt{2}$ and finally $\sigma_4$($\alpha$)=-$\alpha$ and
$\sigma_4$($\sqrt{2}$)=$-\sqrt{2}$. I don't know what's wrong, because according to my calculations the extension is of degree 8 and the statement says that it is galois so there must be 4 more $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms but I don't know what they are. If someone could write them explicitly I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Your MathJAX could use a bit of refinement...  For example, if you want $\alpha$ you would write `$\alpha$`.  Without knowing which symbols you actually want to use, it's not clear how for example the Sigma should be adjusted, perhaps a moment of research or experimentation would tell you which one is appropriate...

Comment: Corrected. Do you know the answer? It is that I need to know. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\alpha=\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}$

$\alpha^2=5+2\sqrt{5}$

$\alpha^2-5=2\sqrt{5}$

$\alpha^4-10\alpha^2+5=0$

Note that $f(x)=x^4-10x^2+5$ is irreducible by Eisenstein criteria with $p=5$, and thus is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}.$ Thus $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=4.$

Now, the four roots of the minimal polynomial of $f(x)$ are $\pm\sqrt{5 \pm 2\sqrt{5}}$  and it can be shown that all of these roots are in $Q(\alpha)$, and thus $f(x)$ splits in $\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}$. Thus $\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}$ is a splitting field for the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and the roots of this minimal polynomial are all distinct. Thus $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q(\alpha)}$ is a Galois extension.

Now, since $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q(\alpha)}$ is a simple extension and the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ splits in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, we have that  $gal(\mathbb{Q(\alpha):\mathbb{Q})} = \{e,\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3\}$ where:

$e(\alpha)=\alpha$

$\gamma_1(\alpha)=-\sqrt{5 + 2\sqrt{5}}$

$\gamma_2(\alpha)=\sqrt{5 - 2\sqrt{5}}$

$\gamma_3(\alpha)=-\sqrt{5 - 2\sqrt{5}}$

$gal(\mathbb{Q(\alpha):\mathbb{Q})}$ is a group of order $4$ and so is isomorphic to either $C_2 \times C_2$ or $C_4$. I leave it as an exercise to you to figure which one it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Could you justify why $\sqrt(5-2\sqrt(5))$ belongs to $F=Q(\alpha)$ and express in function of a base of F. I have not proved that $\sqrt(5- 2\sqrt(5))$ belongs to F nor do I see how to express it as a function of a base.

Comment: The problem statement says that the connection is Galois, therefore the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ must split in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{2})$. So I went ahead and said it splits in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ (because it does) but really you shouldn't need to show it explicitly if you just use the problem statement. Sorry a bit busy atm

Comment: I noticed, but what you said is enough for the rest. The galois group of the large extension is isomorphic to C4×C2 (I already solved it thanks to you).